# How can I run a cron command with existing environmental variables?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, cron

How can I run a cron command with existing environmental variables?

If I am at a shell prompt I can type `echo $ORACLE_HOME` and get a path. This is one of my environmental variables that gets set in my `~/.profile`. However, it seems that `~/.profile` does not get loaded fron cron scripts and so my scripts fail because the `$ORACLE_HOME` variable is not set.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229825/where-can-i-set-environment-variables-that-crontab-will-use) the author mentions creating a `~/.cronfile` profile which sets up variables for cron, and then he does a workaround to load all his cron commands into scripts he keeps in his `~/Cron` directory. A file like `~/.cronfile` sounds like a good idea, but the rest of the answer seems a little cumbersome and I was hoping someone could tell me an easier way to get the same result.

I suppose at the start of my scripts I could add something like `source ~/.profile` but that seems like it could be redundant.

So how can I get make my cron scripts load the variables from my interactive-shell profile?

Comment: How is adding `source ~/.profile` to a program redundant? Programs inherit their environment from the calling program.  If that calling program is not your shell, then how will the decendant program get the environment that you want?

Comment: I already wrote my answer to a similar question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52337579/9264697) It simply uses `su -l` to setup a normal login environment including the $PATH for either root or other specific user.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

In the crontab, before you command, add `. $HOME/.profile`.  For example:

```
0 5 * * * . $HOME/.profile; /path/to/command/to/run
```

`Cron` knows nothing about your shell; it is started by the system, so it has a minimal environment.  If you want anything, you need to have that brought in yourself.

Comment: What does the `.` before the script do? (not sure how I would `man` that). Why is this different from `source`?

Comment: The `.` command is the original command for `source`.  They are equivalent within the shell and a bit easier to type, especially within a crontab.  To get more info, type `help .` or search for `^SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS` in the man page for `bash` or at the top of `man `zshbuiltins`.  Running `type .` will tell you that the command is a builtin.

Comment: Depending on Linux distributions, you may need to change `.profile` by `.bash_profile`. Check which `.profile` file exists in the user's home directory.

Comment: @Arcege This doesn't work for me (Fedora Core 21), and I presume that's because the shell level drops back down. Instead, what DOES work is if you source it.

Comment: It's likely that if it isn't working, it's because the SHELL for the cron script isn't set to bash, so it's not executing the same way you might expect.

Comment: In Ubuntu, `.profile` just calls `.bashrc` which has explicit code to exit if run interactively.

Comment: @cwd, did you try `man .`?  It works on my system.  (It pulls up the man page for Bash builtins, the first of which is `.`.)

Comment: The file was called .bash_profile on my distro (Amazon linux). Worked great.

Comment: I tried with . .bash_profile which works :-)

Comment: The solution is not working for SunOS 5.9

Comment: Was under the impression that sourcing the .profile and then using `;` would cause it to be run in another process that doesn't actually give them over to the command, and that it should be done as `$HOME/.profile && /some/command/here`

Comment: This does not work for `.bashrc` on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: Is it possible to set env variables globally? eg `. /path/env \n * * * * * $MYENV/cmd --par`

Answer (score 65):

Another option, which I find easier, is to run the script with cron and have the environment in the script.

In crontab -e file:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

*/1 * * * * $HOME/cron_job.sh
```

In cron_job.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
source $HOME/.bash_profile
some_other_cmd
```

Any command after the source of .bash_profile will have your environment as if you logged in.

Comment: When running on an AWS Linux AMI, it didn't even occur to me that cron wouldn't be using `/bin/bash` as the shell. I kept wondering why things like `cd /path/to/project; source .vars` would work when I typed them manually but would fail (`File not found`) when included in a cronjob. The key line for me was setting `SHELL=/bin/bash` so that I could actually use familiar bash commands in each cronjob. `/bin/sh/` (the default cron shell, apparently) is very limiting.

Comment: It's too bad you can't specify Environment Files at the top of the cron like you can specify individual environment variables.  Systemd has a `EnvironmentFile` service unit. Too bad cron doesn't have something similar.

Comment: If `$SHELL` is `/bin/sh`, the `source` command does not exist. Use `.` instead.

Comment: The solution is not working for SunOS 5.9. The following error is displayed:
 `SHELL=/bin/bash
 crontab: error on previous line; unexpected character found in line.
 crontab: errors detected in input, no crontab file generated`

Comment: Hmm... I haven't used Sun in years but maybe their version of crontab doesn't support setting a default shell. In your case I would then have something along the lines of `*/1 * * * * /bin/bash $HOME/cron_job.sh`.

Comment: I do this, run the shell script, then after I echo these vars, I see nothing, but If copy paste the source command (source $HOME/.bash_profile) into my shell, then echo I see the variable. What gives?

Comment: @JZ I suggest that you read up on the [source command](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Source_command), [subshell](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/What_is_a_Subshell%3F), and [exporting variables](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Export_Variables).

Answer (score 34):

Another option, which I find easier, is to run the script with cron and tell bash to login (hence using `/etc/profile.d/...` environment definitions)

In `crontab -e` file:

```
*/1 * * * * bash -l -c './cron_job.sh'
*/1 * * * * bash -l -c 'php -f ./cron_job.php'
```

Any command after the source of `.bash_profile` will have your environment as if you logged in.

Answer (score 11):

> Q: How can I run a cron command with existing environmental variables?

The general practice is to specifically set all required environmental variables in a script that is to be run from a cron job.

Comment: I agree with @fpmurphy, that ways it also ensure the secured process environment. If you want to set only few variables from cron you can use `/usr/bin/env` command to set the variables and then can act as the environment process for the cronjob.

Comment: [daemontools' `envdir`](http://thedjbway.b0llix.net/daemontools/envdir.html) comes to mind, too.

Comment: I am all for security, but perhaps I can create a file `~/.cronvars` and include that in the profile and also in my cron scripts. I don't want to hard code environmental variables in each of the scripts I run because when paths change hard coded paths in each file are not easy to maintain. Seems like that would allow a centralized place for the needed variables and still keep other variables from being loaded.

Comment: This answer has been flagged as "not an answer" and I'm inclined to agree. The question asks "How can I run a cron command with existing environmental variables?" not whether it's a good idea or not. If you could amend your answer to show how to solve the problem (by incorporating existing env vars into a script), that would bring it on-topic. Thank you!

Comment: This is true for relatively simple bash scripts. As soon as your script involves other executables, each requiring a proper environment being set, including .bash_profile makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 9):

This syntax definitely helps you. I do not understand the syntax, but it works. Oracle uses this syntax, when deploys Oracle Configuration Manager to crontab, hence, I believe that this is a right solution.

```
0 5 * * * SOME_ENV_VAR=some_value some_command some_parameters
```

Comment: I don't love this solution because it pollutes up the crontab, but yep, it works! Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can put global environment variables in `/etc/environment`.
They are loaded when a program is run by the crontab. Ex :

```
env | grep ORACLE_HOME >> /etc/environment
service crontab restart
```

The drawback is that it is not restricted to a single user.
Tested under CentOS7

Comment: This is a much better method when you want to apply the same environment to tens of lines, instead of editing the whole existing crontab...

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
BASH_ENV=/home/user/.profile
```

to the crontab. See [How to guarantee availability of $BASH_ENV](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138577/how-to-guarantee-availability-of-bash-env/138609#138609)

Answer (score 3):

I recently came across a case where I had to execute the overall cronjob as root but, at the same time, had to execute a subcommand as a different user (which required sourcing that user's environment). I went with the following approach:

```
# m  h  dom  mon  dow  user  command
*/5  *   *    *    *   root  (sudo -i -u <the user> command-to-be-run-as-user) && command-to-be-run-as-root
```

The crucial part is the argument `-i` that's being passed to `sudo` which will execute the given command in a separate login shell (which in turn means that the user's dotfiles will be sourced).

PS: Note that the `user` column is only available in `/etc/crontab` and the `/etc/cron.d/*` files.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting profile, what helped me was setting the `PATH`. Some of the commands were not available in my cron scripts as the `PATH` is different.

```
ENVIRONMENT=prod
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
*/30 * * * * /opt/myscript1.sh
*/30 * * * * /opt/myscript2.sh
*/30 * * * * /opt/myscript3.sh
```

Setting `PATH` with the path of commands helped me. Even better if you can use a template and detemplatize later,

```
ENVIRONMENT={{ENVIRONMENT}}
PATH={{PATH}}
*/30 * * * * /opt/myscript1.sh
*/30 * * * * /opt/myscript2.sh
*/30 * * * * /opt/myscript3.sh
```

Passing variables to each item looks messy.

Answer (score 1):

The solution, which worked for me, is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229825/where-can-i-set-environment-variables-that-crontab-will-use).

You create a wrapper script, which calls `. ~/.cronfile`, and then does the things you want. This script is launched by cron.

In `~/.cronfile` you specify the environment for your cron jobs.

Answer (score -1):

I put . `~/.dbus/session-bus/*` at the top of my desired script :)

Comment: Welcome to U & L SE. Please expand your answer more so that it will benefit the readers.