# How to guarantee availability of $BASH_ENV

Tags: bash, environment-variables

A non-interactive, non-login shell will try to source any script specified in $BASH_ENV.  But how do I guarantee $BASH_ENV is set before a cron job or script has a chance to set $BASH_ENV for any particular session?  Is the only option to compile Bash with it hardcoded?

Comment: Check out `pam_env`.  Or just source `$HOME/.env` in all your scripts.

Answer (score 8):

If you want all the bash scripts in your crontab to load `BASH_ENV`, set it at the crontab level.

```
BASH_ENV=/path/to/startup.bash
12 34 * * * /path/to/bash_script
1 23 1 * * /path/to/other_bash_script
```

If you want to set `BASH_ENV` only for a particular entry, set it there. Then `BASH_ENV` won't be set for the code listed in the crontab itself, but it's a bad idea to put anything complex there anyway.

```
12 34 * * * export BASH_ENV=/path/to/startup.bash; /path/to/bash_script
1 23 1 * * /path/to/other_bash_script
```

If you want a particular script to always load some configuration file, load it directly from within the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
. /path/to/configuration.bash
…
```

Comment: Why do you bother `export`ing `$BASH_ENV` if you're only setting it for a single process? Just `BASH_ENV=/path/to/startup.bash /path/to/bash_script` is the sensible way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

`BASH_ENV` is only read in a **non-interactive** shell, and only if that shell is bash (and not called under the name `sh`, either). A non-login, interactive shell does not look for `$BASH_ENV`:

```
$ export BASH_ENV=/home/cuonglm/bash-env.sh
$ bash -lci '. test.sh'
QWERTY
$ bash -lc '. test.sh'
BASH_ENV read
QWERTY
$ bash -ci '. test.sh'
QWERTY
$ bash -c '. test.sh'
BASH_ENV read
QWERTY
```

There is no standard file that is run in non-interactive shell for user. You should set it in separated file then source it:

```
bash -c '. ~/.profile; echo 123'
```

Or you can set it in some system wide config file like `/etc/environment` or `/etc/bashrc.bashrc`.

Comment: I was hopeful /etc/environment would work, but it's not sourced by any shells in Mac OS 10.6 as far as I can tell.  /etc/bashrc.bashrc sounds intriguing, but I'm having difficulty tracking down any info on it.  Or is that a typo?