# Latexmk, from Makefile, from bash script, from Cron - Latexmk not being executed

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron, latex, gnu-make

I have several Git repositories with LaTeX files that I want to have typeset automatically. The idea is to have a central bash script (run by a cronjob) that executes a bash script in every repository, which (1) pulls new commits and (2) executes `make all`, which should call `latexmk` on the changed LaTeX files.

The central bash script simply contains lines like:

```
bash ./repos/repo-xyx/cron.sh
```

Then in `repos/repo-xyz/cron.sh` is something like:

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
git pull
make all
cd -
```

And in the Makefile in the same directory:

```
all: $(subst .tex,.pdf,$(wildcard *.tex))

%.pdf: %.tex
        latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -shell-escape" $< </dev/null
```

In my user's crontab, I have `* * * * * bash .../cron.sh 2>&1 > .../cron.log` and `SHELL=/bin/bash`.

When the cronjob is executed, I read the following in the log:

```
Already up-to-date.
latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -shell-escape" myfile.tex </dev/null
.../ (this comes from the line "cd -")
```

As you can see, `latexmk` is invocated but doesn't do anything. `myfile.pdf` is not generated.

When I run `bash cron.sh` (as the same user) from the highest directory, this *does* work.

What could cause the Makefile to not execute commands when run from a bash script that is run by a cron job (at least, I think it's make not executing this command)?

This is GNU Make 3.81 on `Linux ubuntu 3.13.0-51-generic #84-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 15 12:08:34 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the path to `pdflatex` was being defined in my `$HOME/.profile`. I thus changed the cronjob to:

```
* * * * * . $HOME/.profile; bash .../cron.sh 2>&1 > .../cron.log
```

in accordance with https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27291/37050.