# I have a sh script. How to run it using crontab?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, cron

I have the following file `execute-backup-from-container.sh`. The content of this file is:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=minime.sql.`date +"%Y%m%d".gz`
CONTAINER='mysql_01'
SCRIPT_ON_CONTAINER='/container-mysql-dump.sh'

${OUTPUT}=$(docker exec ${CONTAINER} /$SCRIPT_ON_CONTAINER)

echo "=============="
echo "$CONTAINER:/$FILE"
echo "=============="
docker cp "$CONTAINER:/$FILE" backup-data/
```

When I run `crontab -e` I am putting the following:
`0 5 * * 1 /home/me/projects/execute-backup-from-container.sh`
This means that the `execute-backup-from-container.sh` should be executed every day at 5:00 am.
The problem is that the script is not executed at all.
So what on earth is the problem? Why is it not executed?

Comment: @steeldriver you are right. If I want to make it every day should I have to put `*` instead of `1`?

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Comment: Also, you have a syntax error in the script: `${OUTPUT}=...` should just be `OUTPUT=...`

Answer (score 5):

The cron fields corresponding to your entry mean:

```
minute:       0 
hour:         5 
day of month: * 
month:        * 
day of week:  1 
command:      /home/me/projects/execute-backup-from-container.sh
```

which translate in English to: Mondays at 5am (any day of the month, any month).

If you want it to be executed:

> every day at 5:00 am

then you want that 5th field to be a `*`:

```
0 5 * * * /home/me/projects/execute-backup-from-container.sh
```

Comment: good point there. I modified the `1` into `*` to be executed every day of the week, but still does not execute the script.

Comment: is there a cron error message in the logs?  Is the script executable?

Comment: No, there are no error messages in the logs. I have read the logs with ` grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

Answer (score 1):

Did you check that the file is set to be executable?  Here is an example of marking a script as executable:

```
$ ls -l test.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 ahill ahill 0 Mar 23 19:30 test.sh
$ chmod +x test.sh
$ ls -l test.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ahill ahill 0 Mar 23 19:30 test.sh
```

The next thing to check is the environment.  cron jobs inherit no environment by default.  The "fix" is discussed here:
[How can I run a cron command with existing environmental variables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27289/how-can-i-run-a-cron-command-with-existing-environmental-variables)

One of the reasons that the environment is a big deal is that cron might not even find bash!  see:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/why-is-cron-not-running-my-sh-script

If you still cannot figure it out, I would do a test: Change your cron job from:

```
0 5 * * * /home/me/projects/execute-backup-from-container.sh
```

to:

```
0 5 * * * /home/me/projects/execute-backup-from-container.sh >> ~/script_errors.log 2>&1
```

What will happen: the next time cron launches the job, error messages produced will be dumped into the text file script_errors.log. (change the path to the script_errors.log file to whatever seems appropriate, but make sure the path exists, though the file does not need to.)

I also noticed something in the OP that might be the real problem:  the word "container."  If the script is inside of a Docker container, then this is likely the solution:
https://www.ekito.fr/people/run-a-cron-job-with-docker/

Comment: This answer misses the point that the schedule used in the crontab is wrong.

Comment: You right... should have looked at that first... but I will leave it here as it might help someone else that is searching.

Comment: Good point with the permissions. I had already put 777 to `execute-backup-from-container.sh` file before posting the question, so it does not help that, but I will check the `environment variable` solution and let you know.

Comment: So I have used the following environment variables but still not working:
`HOME=/home/cristian
LOGNAME=cristian
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash
PWD=/home/cristian
BASH_ENV=/home/cristian/.profile`

Comment: I would do a test:  Change your cron job from:
0 5 * * * /home/me/projects/execute-backup-from-container.sh
to:
0 5 * * * /home/me/projects/execute-backup-from-container.sh >> ~/script_errors.log 2>&1 
What will happen:  the next time cron launches the job, error messages produced will be dumped into the text file script_errors.log.  (change the path to the script_errors.log file to whatever seems appropriate, but make sure the path exists, but he file does not need to.)

Comment: I noticed something in the OP that might be the problem:  The word "container."  If the script is INSIDE a docker container, I bet this is the answer:  https://www.ekito.fr/people/run-a-cron-job-with-docker/

Answer (score 0):

After keeping into account all the answers, the last issue was in the last line:

```
docker cp "$CONTAINER:/$FILE" backup-data/
```

The last line should have been

```
docker cp "$CONTAINER:/$FILE" docker-projects/mysql/backup-data/
```

Thank you all for your support.